# Proof For Formula for Solution to First Order Linear Autonomous System of ODE w/ Complex Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-analysis

I just had a quick question regarding linear autonomous systems of ODE with complex eigenvalues. in class we discussed how the solution can be written in the form $y(t)=e^{a t} QR(t)Q^{-1} y_{0}$ where $R(t)$ is the rotation matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
\cos( bt) & \sin( bt)\\
-\sin( bt) & \cos( bt)
\end{pmatrix}$ for some complex eigenvalues $\lambda = a\pm bi$ and Q is the matrix where each column consists of the real and imaginary parts of our eigenvectors $\mathbf{\vec{v}_1}= \mathbf{\vec{p}}+i\mathbf{\vec{q}}$ and $\mathbf{\vec{v}_2}= \mathbf{\vec{p}}-i\mathbf{\vec{q}}$.

Ive Tried to prove this formula using Euler's identity $e^{a\pm bi)t}=e^{at}(cosbt\pm isint)$ but I'm afraid im stumped, so if anyone has any diea how to prove this formula for our solution when we have complex eigenvalues I would really appreciate it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: upon doing some research I have found that when performing the change of basis $Q^{-1}AQ=C$ we get some $\mathbf{anti-symmetric}$ matrix $C=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$ meaning we can decompose $A$ as $A=QCQ^{-1}$ such that the matrix exponential $e^{At}=Qe^{Ct}Q^{-1}$ by the Taylor series of $e^x$ and the identity $(QCQ^{-1})^n=QC^nQ^{-1}$ then computing the matrix exponential for $e^{Ct}$ and again using the Taylor Series of $e^x$ im getting that I need a formula for this $\mathbf{anti-symmetric}$ $C^n=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}^n$ any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: I thought of trying to do a second Jordan decomposition now on the matrix $C$ and it sort of worked, so maybe my question now is more along the lines of how do I prove that the change of basis $Q^{-1}AQ$ gives me an anti-symmetric matrix of the form I mentioned earlier when the matrix A has complex eigenvalues?